# Conflicting `Encode` and `Decode` Trait Implementations for Type Aliases in a custom pallet

Tags: pallet, substrate-node, traits, zero-knowlage

I'm working on a custom pallet related to the zero-knowledge proof system and I've run into an issue regarding the trait implementations. I have defined a fixed-size hash type H256 using a custom macro `construct_fixed_hash!` provided by the `fixed_hash` crate:

```
construct_fixed_hash!{ pub struct H256(32); }
```

This type is used extensively across my module for cryptographic purposes. For a specific feature, I need to treat this type differently; hence, I introduced a new type alias `GEpoch` for `H256` to represent a distinct conceptual entity:

```
pub type GEpoch = H256;
```

I've implemented the `Encode` and `Decode` traits for the `GEpoch` type, however, on defining it as a storage item inside a pallet like this:

```
#[pallet::storage]
#[pallet::getter(fn g_epoch)]
pub(crate) type LastGEpoch<T: Config> = StorageValue<_, GEpoch>;
```

I'm getting this error:

```
error[E0277]: the trait bound `g_epoch::H256: EncodeLike` is not satisfied
  --> pallets/zk-system/src/lib.rs:50:15
   |
50 |       #[pallet::pallet]
   |  _______________^
51 | |     pub struct Pallet<T>(core::marker::PhantomData<T>);
52 | |
53 | |     #[pallet::event]
...  |
70 | |     #[pallet::getter(fn g_epoch)]
71 | |     pub(crate) type LastGEpoch<T: Config> = StorageValue<_, GEpoch>;
   | |______________________________^ the trait `EncodeLike` is not implemented for `g_epoch::H256`
   |
   = help: the following other types implement trait `EncodeLike<T>`:
             <bool as EncodeLike>
             <i8 as EncodeLike>
             <i16 as EncodeLike>
             <i32 as EncodeLike>
             <i64 as EncodeLike>
             <i128 as EncodeLike>
             <u8 as EncodeLike>
             <u16 as EncodeLike>
           and 333 others
   = note: required for `g_epoch::H256` to implement `FullEncode`
   = note: required for `g_epoch::H256` to implement `FullCodec`
   = note: required for `frame_support::pallet_prelude::StorageValue<_GeneratedPrefixForStorageLastGEpoch<T>, g_epoch::H256>` to implement `StorageInfoTrait`
```

As I understand it, the implementation of `Encode/Decode` traits automatically implements the `EncodeLike` trait, but I'm still getting this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`sp_core::hash` already provides a `H256` type that we normally use for storage. You can still wrap it, but would be better to wrap it in a Rust *newtype*. Implementing traits on type aliases is normally going to produce conflicting implementations, since it is just a rename - not a new type.

You can probably debug it by putting first the `H256` into storage and ensuring that it works and then a wrapped `GEpoch` type.